# Parsing a date string to another form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, parsing, date-formatting

I am getting a date from backend in this form '2020-10-13T12:37:12.636230Z'
I need to change it into dd.mm.yyyy only form.
So how to parse a data coming from backend to a dd.mm.yyyy. Thank you.

UPD:
I didnt explain correctly I guess. Im getting a lot of date feom back to my front in this form 'YYYY-mm-dd T HH:mm:ss.xxZ'. So i need to convert it into DD.MM.YY HH.mm.ss

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: You mean, you want to *format* a date to a specific format.

Comment: yep, I didnt explain correctly I guess.  Im getting a lot of date feom back to my front in this form 'YYYY-mm-dd T HH:mm:ss.xxZ'. So i need to convert it into DD.MM.YY HH.mm.ss

Comment: JavaScript's `Date` object can parse the ISO8601 format directly. You can format a Date using any of the `to...String()` methods, although they don't allow you to specify any format. JavaScript is rather limited when it comes to dates. If `toLocaleDateString()` doesn't produce what you want you may have to use a separate library like date-fns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`Date#toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```js
const source = '2020-10-13T12:37:12.636230Z';
const date = new Date(source).toLocaleDateString('de-DE');

console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using this method

```
const formateDate = (inputVal) => {
        inputVal = new Date(inputVal);
        let dd = inputVal.getDate(), 
        mm = inputVal.getMonth() + 1,
        yyyy = inputVal.getFullYear();

        if (dd < 10) { 
            dd = '0' + dd; 
        } 
        if (mm < 10) { 
            mm = '0' + mm; 
        }

        return dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy;
}


formateDate('2020-10-13T12:37:12.636230Z');
```